# Java 8 - List Results are Printing Not Actual Content

Tags: java, java-8

Using Java 8, I was checking out some of its new features...

Created the following class:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Created the PersonApp class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

public class PersonApp {

    public static void printSorted(List<Person> people, Comparator<Person> comparator) {
        people.stream()
              .sorted(comparator)
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

        people.add(new Person("Sara", 12));
        people.add(new Person("Mark", 43));
        people.add(new Person("Bob", 12));
        people.add(new Person("Jill", 64));

        printSorted(people, comparing(Person::getAge).thenComparing(Person::getName));
    }
}
```

When I run this class, I get the following instead of the values I wanted to see:

```
Person@682a0b20
Person@3d075dc0
Person@214c265e
Person@448139f0
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Override `toString()` in `Person`.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4.

Comment: I'm quite surprised you're able to write stream code but don't know about `toString`. Are you learning the language in the right order ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: You are missing a `toString` implementation in your `Person` class.

**Explanation**:
`System.out.println` calls the `toString` method on the passed object and prints the output.

In this case you are passing a `Collection`(`List`) to be printed, which in turn calls the `toString` method on each member of the collection (see implementation of `AbstractCollection.toString`), which in this case happen to be objects of your `Person` class.

Since you haven't overridden `toString` in your `Person` class, `Object.toString` gets invoked (all Java classes implicitly extend `Object` class), and that's why you get the output as `Person@123456`, because `Object.toString` is implemented as:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Comment: Np, but your answer is a bit short. Although it's a basic question which problem has a hundred duplicates, you could explain it a bit better.